# How Do I fsck the root?

Tags: root

how do I fsck the root? normally I'm only able to do so when I can't boot into ubuntu and end up at busybox most of the time but idk how to get to busybox on purpose

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to run

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

and reboot.

This will create an empty `/forcefsck` file that will tell the system to check all partitions at boot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you can't fsck a mounted disk, and if you booted off that disk (presumably you did under normal conditions) you therefore cannot check it. It's worth noting that I believe your main disk is fsck'ed automatically during boot in *some circumstances*, though I'm not sure what those circumstances are in modern installations.

Anyway, to check your disk manually, boot your hardware from an install disk and get it into "Try Ubuntu" mode. From there, launch a terminal window, and if you do: `sudo fsck -l` you should see your real hard disk (probably /dev/sda) sitting there. But at this point, it's not mounted, so you should be able to run an fsck on it.